# .Assembly / GetExportedTypes throws FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, reflection

If I run this code:

```
var myAsm = typeof(MyType).Assembly;
var types = myAsm.GetExportedTypes();
```

I get:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly ....
```

which lists a dependent assembly.  However, if I do:

```
var myAsm = Assembly.LoadFrom(...);  // DLL containing the same assembly as above
var types = myAsm.GetExportedTypes();
```

it works fine.

I really would prefer the first technique, as it's cleaner... why should I have to load a DLL that is already loaded?  Any advice?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is that DLLs are often delay-loaded until the type is actually used. Are you sure the DLL has been loaded? (Have you previously used MyType yet?)

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but I just had a related problem to this and I thought I'd post some info to help others who may stumble across this as I did!

`Assembly` has

```
.LoadFile(string path)
```

and

```
.LoadFrom(string path)
```

`LoadFile` will throw a `FileNotFoundException` if loading the assembly from some remote (not the same as the executing dll) folder. You need to use `LoadFrom` as you do above ;)

Comment: Just wanted to say THANKYOU for this post!  
I added some stuff to our automated tests and suddenly the build was failing, but all the tests passed. Our PS script that ran the tests was trying to pull a list of tests from the DLL with GetExportedTypes() and we were getting this error. The problem was that we were using LoadFile() and I guess it wasn't loading a dependency of a dependency or something. Whatever, changing LoadFile to LoadFrom fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
```

Or

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyType));
```

The reason your second one works is you are actually loading a .dll.  When you call typeof(MyType).Assembly, it has no idea which .dll reflection should be using.  Which is why either `GetExecutingAssembly` or `GetAssembly(tyepof(MyType))` should work.

Comment: The first one would not give me the right assembly.  The second one gave me the same FileNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to Load an Assembly that *IS NOT* the ExecutingAssembly, and that DLL has references to lower-level objects like MyProj.Interfaces or MyProj.BaseClasses or Infragistics controls or something like that...  THOSE dll's will also have to be available in the same folder from which you are loading the initial dll.